# Undo TFVC check-out for deleted user

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I am attempting to undo pending changes for a user that no longer exists in our organization. DevOps will not allow me to work with the workspace or identity at all, indicating the user is not a valid identity:

**TF14045: The identity XXXXXXXX, XXX is not a recognized identity.**

We don't care about any pending changes, we just want the (shared) locks removed.

Can this be done? Thanks all.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm working with our security people to make sure that is not an issue. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you don't need to remove the locks? Or you have other methods solve the issue? Maybe you can share us your solution.

Comment: No, I am still unable to remove the locks. Our security people are supposed to look at whether or not I even have the correct permissions. I am an admin, but apparently that is not enough.

Comment: It seems the error is not related to your permission, but the user account is not in your organization. You can try to run command `tf vc workspaces /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com /owner:<email>` to see whether you can list this user's workspace.

Answer (score 2):

When you run commands to work with the workspace, try using their email address instead of their display name. For example, list that user's workspace with the command below:

```
tf vc workspaces /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com /owner:<email>
```

Then run `tf workspace /delete` to delete the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the rights to unlock others code see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#tfvc-object-level

Then you should be able to use the TF command to unlock files.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/lock-command?view=azure-devops
(You'll want to use /lock:none to remove the lock)

I'm also pretty sure that if you delete the workspace of the user that left he lock will be removed, check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=azure-devops

From this article: "If you delete a workspace that contains pending changes, **Team Foundation cancels the pending changes as part of the delete process**. Deleting a workspace does not delete the files and folders on the client computer that were in that workspace."

Good luck